# Prevent MVC view submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to integrate a payment api into my MVC 5 asp.net C# app.

The 1st part involves getting a 'token' from that api without submitting my form.

I am relatively new to mvc and I cannot get this to work.

This part of my markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewCard", "Payments", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Card Number</span>
            <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" value="4242424242424242"/>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>CVC</span>
            <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" value="1223"/>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label>
            <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
            <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" value="10" />
        </label>
        <span> / </span>
        <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"  value="2022"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
</form>
}

$('#payment-form').submit(function (event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    event.preventDefault();         //i added this is!
    return false; //from the sample code!
});
```

the form still submits/posts back.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have invalid html (nested `<form>` elements) and the outer form is submitting. Remove the inner

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
```

tag and if you want to refer to an `id` (you could just use `$('form').submit(function (event) {`) then change the outer form to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewCard", "Payments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "payment-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Your script will now handle that - your `return false;` will prevent the default submit of the form (and you do not need the `event.preventDefault();`). Previously the script only handled the (invalid) inner form and did nothing to stop the default submit of the outer form)

Comment: hi, after setting a break-point I can see that my script is not being called. Can I add a function to call in the 'Html.BeginForm' bit to call my function before submitting (which will then stop the submit?

Comment: Did you add `new { id = "payment-form" }` to the `BeginForm()`? The code  you have shown will work fine if your make the changes in my answer.

Comment: Then if its not working, your have something else in your code that you have not shown us (and I assume you also removed the closing `</form>` tag at the bottom). Just double check the generated html to ensure that its now `<form ...... id="payment-form" .... >`

Comment: Well I just copied the code in your question into my project, made the changes as per my answer and commented out `Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);` and it works perfectly - the button is disabled and the form is not submitted

Comment: Move `event.preventDefault();` as the first line of `$('#payment-form').submit(function (event) {` and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104390/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-andrew-simpson).